Error "can't adapt type 'dict'" when Inserting a dictionary into a table using psycopg2.sql
I have a postgresql table:


create table if not exists public.test
(
    id integer,
    name varchar,
    months jsonb
);



I have a json:


[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "name_tset",
        "months": [
            {
                "month": 7,
                "year": 2024,
                "days_in_month": 29,
                "fact": "0",
            }
        ]
    },
    ...
]



When I want to insert data, the error "can't adapt type 'dict'" appears.  I know it's because of the "month" dictionary list, but how do I add my code to make it work? Without "month", the insertion into the table is successful.
My code:


for d in data:
    columns_list = list(d.keys())
    insert_query = sql.SQL("INSERT INTO {schema}.{table_name} ({columns}) VALUES ({values})").format(
        schema=sql.Identifier(f'{schema}'),
        table_name=sql.Identifier(f'{table_name}'),
        columns=sql.SQL(",").join(map(sql.Identifier, columns_list)),
        values=sql.SQL(",").join(map(sql.Placeholder, columns_list))
    )
    cursor.execute(insert_query, d)




Does this answer your question?

One way to do this:
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import Json
from psycopg2 import SQL

con = psycopg2.connect(dbname='test', user='postgres', port=5432)
cur = con.cursor()

data = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "name_tset",
        "months": [
            {
                "month": 7,
                "year": 2024,
                "days_in_month": 29,
                "fact": "0",
            }
        ]
    }
]

columns_list = list(data[0].keys())
schema = "public"
table_name = "test"

insert_query = sql.SQL("INSERT INTO {schema}.{table_name} ({columns}) VALUES ({values})").format(
        schema=sql.Identifier(schema),
        table_name=sql.Identifier(table_name),
        columns=sql.SQL(",").join(map(sql.Identifier, columns_list)),
        values=sql.SQL(",").join(map(sql.Placeholder, columns_list))
    )

for d in data:
    cur.execute(insert_query, {"id": d["id"], "name": d["name"], "months": Json(d["months"])}

con.commit()

The above pulls the dict apart to allow for using the Json adaptation function on the months data. For more on JSON adaptation see JSON
This yields:
select * from test ;
-[ RECORD 1 ]----------------------------------------------------------
id     | 1
name   | name_tset
months | [{"fact": "0", "year": 2024, "month": 7, "days_in_month": 29}]


